# unique a large scale array/sequence

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, unique, mpi

I want to unique an array of **n** elements.

**n** can be up to 10^9, and even 10^11.

That is, the elements may not all fit in the memory. So the naive **sort** and **unique** approach below will not work( too slow: sort and unique a 10^8 array takes half a minute by one thread ).

`sort( a.begin(), a.end() );
a.erase( unique(a.begin(), a.end() ), a.end() );`

Luckily, there is something help to design the algorithm:

- The elements fit in the 64-bit unsigned integer( uint64_t ). Since the elements are generated by a hash function, so we can assume it **satisfies uniform distribution**( ~U(0, 2^64-1) ).
- I have a cluster of no less than 10 multicore computers/nodes, so **the algorithm can (and should) be designed distributed**. And I have the authority to run the MPI C++ code. ( However, the cluster do not belong to myself, sometimes there may be other programs competing for the CPU time on any computer/node. So the tasks are better dispatched to each computer/node dynamically )
- Each computer/nodes have no less than 8 cores, no less than 64G main memory, and no less than 100G SSD free space. Moreover, they are connected by Gigabit Ethernet.

Could anyone help to give any suggestion on designing the algorithm? The approach is in need to run multi time. I wish to get the result in one hour on the cluster.

Comment: Are there a lot of duplicates ore are they quite rare?

Comment: You could try std::set?

Comment: I am not sure "Are there a lot of duplicates or are they quite rare?" Without the experimental result. I could only assume it **satisfies uniform distribution**.

Comment: You should rehash into a smaller hash space, say 32bit, distribute the bins accross the cluster and remove duplicates within each bin in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Split your data into 2 parts. Assuming one part will fit in memory easily. Sort and make every part unique. Save it to a file (can be done concurrently). Like merging two sorted sets you only need the head of every part. Processed elements can be written to disk.

Generalization from 2 to N parts is easy.

Answer (score 1):

You may also have a look at the references given [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969813/which-parallel-sorting-algorithm-has-the-best-average-case-performance) for parallel sorting algorithms to get some inspiration :-)