# Scala - Sorting par sequences

Tags: list, scala, sorting, par, parallel-collections

```
val data :Seq[Something] = ...
val transformed = data.par.map transform toList
val sorted = transformed.sortWith(...)
```

How can I get rid of the `toList` when sorting par sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking whether there is a parallel sorting implementation for parallel collections in the standard library, the answer is no. If you just want to get rid of the `toList`, I suggest `.seq`.

In terms of performance, there i no penalty to go from a parallel collection to a seq. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23703476/1553233) for more detail. Also if you check at the [implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/collection/parallel/mutable/ParArray.scala) you can see that `.seq` returns the `arrayseq` which is the main structure storing the elements in the ParArray, without any modification.

Comment: So there really is no way to sort without transforming? Sucks. Does `.seq` offer any benefits over `.toList` (e.g. time)?