# std::sort is way more fast than custom OpenMP parallel sorting algorithm

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I've been testing parallel sorting using OpenMP. I implemented odd-even sorting algorithm that is 3x faster than without OpenMP. However, std::sort is still way more faster: seq - 100s, parallel - 20s, std::sort - 0.05s

I tried moving #pragma omp parallel for to i-cycle but that worked even worse and did not sort the vector

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int j = (i % 2) ? 0 : 1; j < 100000 - 1; j += 2) {
            if (vec_[j] > vec_[j + 1]) {
                std::swap(vec_[j], vec_[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Tbh, I expected parallel odd-even sort to be the fastest but now I wonder - am I doing anything wrong or it is just std::sort is SO efficient?

Comment: It seems like `std::swap` may also run in parallel given certain circumstances. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43162632/10411602 Besides, an improved bubble sort isn't going to beat something like an introsort, which is what STL uses.

Comment: how many threads? If the sequential version takes only 0.05 seconds I would not expect any speed up from putting more threads, I'd rather expect to see the overhead coming from using threads

Comment: Is the complexity of your algorithm logarithmic?  From the surface, it looks like a plain old (slow, O(n*n)) bubble sort with a few tweaks.  `std::sort` is logarithmic in nature.

Comment: more threads does not always result in faster execution. In fact problems that benefit from adding more and more threads are extremely rare. Try to increase the workload

Comment: 1. Cache ownership of cores most likely causes slowdown when parallelized.
2. As you noticed top cycle can't be parallelized simply because one iteration depends on result of previous
3. std::sort is efficient, that's why it's in std. usually, it's a combination of quick and insertion sort which are both algorithmically superior to even-odd

Comment: @user463035818 CPU is 8 threads. It doesn't matter how many integers do I input - std::sort is still faster

Comment: I think @PaulMcKenzie explained that well. You have a slow algorithm. Adding 8 threads does not make up for the difference between O(n long n) and O(n^2)

Comment: If your _O(n^2)_ algorithm takes 100 [s] when run single-threaded, you would need 2000 threads to reduce it to 0.05 [s]. In the ideal case with perfect linear speedup.

Comment: Also the fact that you're testing with 100k elements... Maybe bump it up to 100M elements and you'll have a significant enough workload to see a difference.

Comment: [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+n*n%2F8+vs+n*log(n)+from+1+to+1000) is a plot that shows the difference in behaviour between `n*n/8` and `n*log(n)`.

Comment: That graph shows that 8 threads with this algorithm will never be better than a single threaded std::sort. The graph may better at `n` less than 35 or so but the time to create threads is not considered and also other factors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your algorithm is O(n^2) in total work done.  Using k threads, this at most makes it O(n^2/k).

`std::sort` is O(n lg n).  Unless k is O( n / lg n ) adding more threads won't keep up.

And even if you *did* have piles of threads. NUMA on most mega-thread systems means that your memory is going to be a serious pain.  The threads don't access the same memory in each cycle, and in fact constantly pass data back and forth.

An example of a way that *might* speed up your work compared to a simple std::sort would be to split the data into K pieces, `std::sort` each of the K pieces, then do a parallel merge of those pieces.

```
int data_count = 100000;
auto get_block_edge = [data_count](int i, int n) {
  return data_count * i / n;
};
int blocks = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
{
  blocks = omp_get_num_threads();
  int block = omp_get_thread_num();
  int start = get_block_edge( block, blocks );
  int finish = get_block_edge( block+1, blocks );
  std::sort( std::begin(vec_)+start, std::begin(vec_)+finish );
}
```

now we have a bunch of sorted blocks.  You just need to merge them.

```
for (int merge_step = 1; merge_step < blocks; merge_step *= 2 )
{
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < (blocks/2/merge_step); ++i) {
    int start = get_block_edge(i*2*merge_step, blocks);
    int mid = get_block_edge(i*2*merge_step+merge_step, blocks);
    int finish = get_block_edge(i*2*merge_step+2*merge_step, blocks);
    finish = std::min(finish, data_count);
    auto b = std::begin(vec_);
    std::inplace_merge( b+start, b+mid, b+finish );
  }
}
```

I think that should be a highly parallel merge.  Or, more likely, segfault because I have an off-by-1 error.

Now, this is still O(n) with an infinite number of threads, as the very last merge has to be single-threaded.  Getting around that is, to say it mildly, tricky.

Comment: For this you will probably have to increase the size of the dataset to see the parallel gain since 0.05 seconds (time to sort the whole thing using std::sort) is already small.

Comment: @drescherjm 1/20th of a second is an eon for pure data manipulation.  I'd be surprised if we couldn't make it faster with careful use of threads.  Maybe not the code above, but still.

Comment: I was thinking of the cost to create the threads. Although this (at least some of the answers) tells me I don't have to worry so much about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929774/how-much-overhead-is-there-when-creating-a-thread

Comment: @drescherjm There is nothing requiring threads to be created there.  Idle threads in a thread pool could be used (if not by OpenMP (I cannot guarantee what OpenMP does), then by a different threaded sort implementation).  There is a required inter-thread communication overhead, but that is small on the scale of 0.05 seconds.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Your `get_block_edge` seem weird. The first block is `0` therefore you are dividing by 0, isn't?

Comment: @nowox I believe I documented the fact it has an off by 1 error already.  :)  I think I might have n and i backwards.  One sec.

Comment: @nowox yep - n and i where backwards.  Swapped them.  Dyslexic math.  Refardless, there are likely to be other problems as I wrote a parallel sorting algorithm in my head using unfamiliar threading primitives without compiling or testing it.  Do not treat it as safe code!  It is pseudo code that looks like C++ omp code.