# Comparing Performance of Parallel Sorting: std::sort vs std::execution::par vs OpenMP

Tags: c++, sorting, parallel-processing

I've been experimenting with different parallel sorting techniques in C++ and conducted a performance comparison between:

1. Regular `std::sort`
2. Parallel `std::sort` utilizing `std::execution::par`
3. Custom parallel sort using OpenMP

I ran the tests on a dataset of 20 million integers. Here are the elapsed times for each sorting method:

```
$ g++ -std=c++20 -fopenmp -pthread sort.cpp -o sort && ./sort
Building a vector of random integers...
Sorting with std::sort...
Elapsed time: 6.1555 s
Sorting with std::sort and std::execution::par...
Elapsed time: 6.45905 s
Sorting with OpenMP...
Elapsed time: 1.05043 s

$ g++ -std=c++20 -fopenmp -pthread sort.cpp -O3 -o sort 
Building a vector of random integers...
Sorting with std::sort...
Elapsed time: 1.1355 s
Sorting with std::sort and std::execution::par...
Elapsed time: 1.14028 s
Sorting with OpenMP...
Elapsed time: 0.224919 s

g++ -v 2>&1 | tail -n1   
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
```

The OpenMP implementation significantly outperformed the others, which was surprising, especially considering that the parallel `std::sort` with `std::execution::par` took even longer than the regular `std::sort`. I'm curious to understand the underlying reasons for these performance results.

Here's the code I used for the benchmark:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <execution>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <omp.h> // Include the OpenMP header

#define N 20'000'000

bool is_sorted(std::vector<int> &v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++)
        if (v[i] > v[i + 1]) return false;
    return true;
}

// Fixed solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56079287/2612235
void omp_sort(std::vector<int> &v) {
    const int data_count = v.size();
    auto get_block_edge = [data_count](int i, int n) {
        return data_count * i / n;
    };

    int blocks = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        blocks = omp_get_num_threads();
        int block = omp_get_thread_num();
        int start = get_block_edge(block, blocks);
        int finish = get_block_edge(block + 1, blocks);
        std::sort(std::begin(v) + start, std::begin(v) + finish);
    }

    for (int merge_step = 1; merge_step < blocks; merge_step *= 2) {
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i += 2 * merge_step) {
            int start = get_block_edge(i, blocks);
            int mid = std::min(get_block_edge(i + merge_step, blocks), data_count);
            int finish = std::min(get_block_edge(i + 2 * merge_step, blocks), data_count);
            if (mid < finish)
                std::inplace_merge(std::begin(v) + start, std::begin(v) + mid, std::begin(v) + finish);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Building a vector of random integers..." << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> data(N);
    std::vector<int> v(N);
    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), std::rand);
    v = data;

    std::cout << "Sorting with std::sort..." << std::endl;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end - start;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " s\n";
    assert(is_sorted(v));
    v = data;

    std::cout << "Sorting with std::sort and std::execution::par..." << std::endl;
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::sort(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end());
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed = end - start;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " s\n";
    assert(is_sorted(v));
    v = data;

    std::cout << "Sorting with OpenMP..." << std::endl;
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    omp_sort(v);
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed = end - start;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " s\n";
    assert(is_sorted(v));
}
```

I ensured that the sorted results are indeed sorted correctly using the `is_sorted` function. I'm particularly interested in why the `std::execution::par` version didn't perform as well as I expected, and why the OpenMP version is so much faster. Is there any room for improvement in the code, or is this performance discrepancy attributable to the nature of the algorithms and the overhead of managing parallel tasks?

My setup:

Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10900KF CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3696 Mhz, 10 Core(s), 20 Logical Processor(s)
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 128 GB

Comment: What if you add `-O2` or `-O3` to your compile command line to enable optimization?

Comment: With `-O3` I obviously don't get any results :), with `-O2` I am better in all results, but in the same proportions

Comment: Why would you obviously get no results with `-O3`?

Comment: Because the array will never be sorted

Comment: But without optimization, the benchmark is clearly biased (e.g. especially since `std::sort` use another algorithm). You need to add a kind of checksum to defeat the compiler optimizing out completely useful parts of the code, not to disable optimizations (which are generally always enabled in real-world in-production applications).

Comment: `-O3` works here https://godbolt.org/z/sW9WfcbhW and on two different machines I tested with 12 and 32 threads. The Compiler Explorer tests were modified to 10M from 20M to work within the time limit and there's only 2 threads available there but not seeing the obvious issue you apparently had.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Well you are right. I don't know what happened when I tried. I'll edit my answer to add `-O3` results