# How to use more cpu with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to calculate time of 3 different sort algorithms. When the program is working , my cpu usage in this application is %12 in task manager and i want to run it with max cpu power. How can i do it?

...

```
auto t1 = Clock::now();
insertionSort(A1, size);
auto t2 = Clock::now();

cout << "insertionSort time: ";
cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count() / 1000000000.0f;
cout << " Seconds.\n";
```

...

Working correctly but not using all cpu.

Comment: What is in this sort implementation that allows it to make use of multiple CPU cores? 12% is (essentially) 1/8, so I suspect you have a non-concurrent sort on an 8 core CPU.

Comment: @Richard Isn't the percentage usually per-core? So you could in fact use up to 800% CPU.

Comment: @BoBTFish depends on how it is measured. If you are looking at Task Manager (or Process Explorer) then 100% is all CPUs each at 100%.

Comment: I have never done it my self but maybe you can increase the priority of your program with [`SetPriorityClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setpriorityclass?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @BoBTFish I have same result in small inputs too.

Comment: @Richard My cpu is i7 7700k , this have 4 cores right?

Comment: A i7 7700k is indeed 4 cores, but it is also two hardware threads per core (Intel calls this "Hyper-threading", so the OS and applications see it as 8 core.

Comment: @wes i have the same result.

Comment: @Richard yes , you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably two different causes of this.

Firstly, your program is probably not [CPU-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound). That is, the CPU is not the bottle-neck so it has to idle while memory access et.c. is taking place.

Secondly, your program is not [Multi-threaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)). That is, it cannot take advantage of the multiple [cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) in your CPU. There are parallel sorting algorithms you can take a look at. Here is a good starting point: [Which parallel sorting algorithm has the best average case performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969813/which-parallel-sorting-algorithm-has-the-best-average-case-performance)