# Multi-Threaded Merge Sort slower than the iterative approach C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, optimization, mergesort

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

void mergeSort(std::vector<int>& v, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

        std::thread t1(mergeSort, std::ref(v), left, mid);
        std::thread t2(mergeSort, std::ref(v), mid + 1, right);

        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        merge(v, left, mid, right);
    }
}
```

I tried a multi threading approach for the merge sort algorithm, but when testing the difference between multi threaded and iterative even with inputs as large as 1M the iterative approach was way faster.
What is wrong with my algorithm and how can I make it work as expected?

Comment: Not everything is going to be faster with threads. In fact, this might be way slower if you spawn lots of threads. You may want to split the list into N parts, then merge those back in later if you want some parallelization here, but perhaps a more [concurrent sorting algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969813/which-parallel-sorting-algorithm-has-the-best-average-case-performance) is a better choice.

Comment: _"how can I make it work as expected?"_  What were you expecting?  Why were you expecting that?

Comment: Using threads is expensive for individual operations that are otherwise relatively fast.  Usually you'll need to manage worker thread pools (to avoid spawning large numbers of threads, especially if you exceed your processor count), and do sets of lengthy operations (e.g. multiples of scheduling cycles -- 200 ms / task)  to see much benefit.

Comment: This code creates an awful lot of thread, and creating a thread takes a long time. Do a bit of analysis: how many threads does it create to sort 2 elements? How many for 4? How may for 8?

Comment: You spawn threads for every single recursion. Many of those threads aren't doing enough work to justify their creation. Typically, you'd break the array into some set number of chunks (likely based on hardware capabilities), which each thread will fully sort, then those sorted chunks get merged in your "main" thread.

Comment: Imagine that each thread allocates *wired* stack space, and initializes a thread id structure that is not trivial in size with the operating system.  That allocation and structure initialization has some overhead, and a non-inconsiderate footprint size.  Also, all those `join` mean that current commander-thread is waiting for the subordinate threads to finish.  That could be a lot of waiting.

Comment: It is often easier to write multithreaded code that is slower than the original than it is to write multithreaded code that is faster than the original.

Comment: Here's also the obligatory hint that there's a `std::sort` overload which takes an execution policy parameter as its first argument which lets you do parallel sorting, all built into C++17: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-c17-parallel-algorithms-for-better-performance

This is "properly" implemented and is indeed faster. Spawning threads on every recursion is clearly a performance killer, this has to be implemented more intelligently with e.g. thread pooling at least.

Comment: I highly recommend having X number of threads (to be determined experimentally).  Each thread should be able to handle more than one task.  Send each one a *message* with a task to perform.  This will reduce your overhead of creating many threads.

Answer (score 2):

With threads, it's important to consider the following:

- What is the maximum number of threads can I actually run at once (given my hardware?). Often the number of logical cores on a system.
- How can I reduce the frequency of threads being started/joined? Starting a thread is an expensive operation, and the work a thread does needs to outweigh the cost of starting it.
- How (although this is less important for your particular use case) can I reduce the amount that threads access the same data as much as possible?

In your case, I think you're ending up spawning far, far more threads than your system can realistically handle. Let's take the simplest example and say you're on a dual-core machine; you would want to split your work across two threads for maximum throughput.

You might want something like:

```
void mergeSort(std::vector<int>& v, int left, int right, bool shouldThread) {
    if (left < right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (shouldThread) {
            std::thread t1(mergeSort, std::ref(v), left, mid, false);
            std::thread t2(mergeSort, std::ref(v), mid + 1, right, false);

            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        }
        else
        {
            mergeSort(std::ref(v), left, mid, false);
            mergeSort(std::ref(v), mid + 1, right, false);
        }

        merge(v, left, mid, right);
    }
}
```

This would start the first level across two threads, and each would recurse down half of the tree.

Assuming this works (untested), your next step would be to make it start threads as far as you have useful hardware to execute them. But I'd check that you understand this level first.

Comment: Your `else` case calls are missing an argument, are they not? It's also possible to determine the number of threads available in the code. A multi-threaded merge sort is considerably more complicated than "merge sort but with threads". Because in your dual core scenario, you would only want to spawn **one** thread and not two. Because your `main()` is already using a thread.

Comment: @sweenish I don’t think this is quite how it works. The main() thread will be stalled on the join() calls; it’s okay to have multiple waiting threads (within reason), the practical consideration is number of actively executing threads.

Answer (score 0):

Limit the number of threads to the number of cores or 2x the number of cores. Link to an example 4 thread merge sort, which is 3 times faster than a single thread merge sort.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/148025/59065